# Memory Leaks in NSBundle iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak in my iOS app, some of the leaks were due to my code written which i was able to fix. But this i was unable to know what the issue was. Any one who can help me with this.

This is the screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and include a [example] with relevant code.

Comment: The memory graph (shown in your screen shot) can be very helpful, but it's a blunt instrument; all it does is draw you a picture. To find out what's really going on, use Instruments (Allocations and Leaks instruments). This will show you the actual chain of calls that generated the leaking object, if there is one. That way, you can focus on your code (if your own code is in fact responsible).

Comment: @koen Thank you. I appreciate your help

Comment: Thank you @matt I was able to resolve it with Instruments.